# What kind of bridge circuit is this?

Tags: potentiometer, bias, bridge

[image]

While I was analyzing the old Tektronix' sampling oscilloscope, I found the above circuit that is adjusting the bias voltage of the sampling gate diodes. I understand its purpose, but could not identify what kind of bridge circuit it is and its theory of operation (i.e., calculation of the network). Can anyone point me out how to start analyzing such circuit? I'm referring to the bridge circuit composed of 5.1kΩ, 14.7kΩ, 22kΩ, and two pots (R22 and R30).

Comment: Schematics of complex systems don't get better than those found from the better years of Tektronix. I don't think I can help you understand a complex system when you present it from the bottom up, in drips and drabs. Context matters. And if there is one thing I've felt a lack with respect to your questions, it is that *context*. My process is to first go over a schematic and identify the recognizable topologies. Where they aren't recognized, I study them in more detail one by one until they are. Then I let the resulting panorama sink in. Once it has, then I can go back and study each section.

Comment: I'm still impressed by your effort. And I suspect you understand a lot of the context. But you are stripping the outer understanding from the narrowed question. That doesn't help me, unfortunately. This only means *I* can't be of much help. But others who already have been through such a system from Tek may be of use without it. I'm fine with that. But I must just stand by.

Comment: If you have the full Tektronix manual on that model you may be able to read up on the circuit operation. Their manuals were often very detailed with lots of calibration and troubleshooting information. There is almost certainly a section that explains the procedure for calibrating the two pots, just that section may give some insight to the circuit's function.

Comment: To all above, thanks for the comments and suggestions. To Nedd, yes I've read their manuals, but I realized most of their circuit description is only covering the surface, and details are somewhat lacking. If you've read those manuals in detail, you may agree with me to some extent. Even on top of that, I want to understand how those circuit designers come up with a specific design for their needs.

Comment: @periblepsis I understand that you mentioned "you cannot answer 'why' such design decisions are made' in my previous questions multiple times. But I am posting these questions to understand 'why' and circuit designer's design decision mechanisms. Understanding the higher level and what the system does is relatively easy and very well written in articles. However, devils are always in details and this is something I am trying to dig up.

Comment: I'm only saying that ***I*** lack the schematics, the blocks, and the perspectives. That's all. I can only help out if I have performed the investigations myself and can place these tidbits into context or else you provide enough context for me. I'm fine letting it rest there. Nothing being forced here. I am just telling you about my problem. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting what I've found for future reference. After playing around with this, I found that R30 is for coarse tuning and R22 is for fine tuning. 22k R is added to set the minimum resistance in case the pot is set to its minimum resistance, which could be 0 Ω. Of course, +225V and -138V is to set the upper and lower bound of the bias voltage for sampling gates.